# How to view what is my Task to KeyGroup to Key assignment in flink-sql application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have flink-sql application that just perform simple simple insert into enrich table by joining multiple tables.

```
create table T1 (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'T1', ...)
create table T2 (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'T2', ...)
create table enrich (...) WITH ( 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka','topic' = 'enrich', ...)
```

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_t1 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM T1)
WHERE rownum = 1;

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_t2 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM T2)
WHERE rownum = 1;

```
insert into enrich 
select ... from distinct_t1 t1 inner join distinct_t2 t2 ... t2.t1_id = t1.id and t2.client_id=t1.client_id
```

Note:

1. Kafka partitions are 8 on raw topics and parallelism is set 8 Max
2. Max Parallelism is default (i believe that is 128 lower bound)
3. TaskSlot=1 and total 8 TaskManagers processing are running

**Question1: Where can i see key groups assignment to tasks (i have 1 taskSlot)**

**Question2: Where can i see keys(data) to keygroups mapping in my running application?**

**Question3: Columns used in join(like t1.client_id,t1.id) become the key and shuffle to land to same keygroup ?? or columns defined in primary key also used and trigger shuffle in source operators ??**

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions 1 and 2 is that this information is not presented anywhere. This is an implementation detail that you're not expected to care about. All that should matter to you is that for any specific distinct key, all messages with that same key value will be sent to the same task slot, regardless of which task is sending the message.

What the implementation does is to deterministically compute the key group for each key using this formula

```
keygroupId = MathUtils.murmurHash(key.hashCode()) % maxParallelism
```

where `maxParallelism` is the total number of key groups; the default value is 128.

Key groups are deterministically assigned to slots using this formula:

```
slotId = keygroupId * parallelism / maxParallelism
```

I don't understand question 3, but perhaps this is enough information for you to figure it out yourself.